# Spring MVC+Hibernate+MSSQL Server concurrent persist find merge deadlock

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc, jmeter, deadlock

My code is as following,

```
em.persist(entity);
em.flush();

Entity ent = em.find(Entity.class, entityPK);
ent.setSomePropertiy("Modified Value");

em.merge(ent);
```

While I did normal testing it works fine. 
But with concurrent user like 10 users with 25 sec ramp up in Jmeter, it produces deadlock with LockAquisitionException during update.
I do have @Version for optimistic concurrency handling in each entity.
My project is Spring MVC 4.2 with hibernate 4.3.7 and MSSql server 2012.

My Basic Query Log:

```
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)
update MyTable set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE PK = ? and version = ? 

insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)
update MyTable set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE PK = ? and version = ? 

insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)
update MyTable set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE PK = ? and version = ?
```

When queries are running as above, it works fine but with increased load while I am running it with concurrent users by Jmeter; it becomes as following which is causing deadlock;

```
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)

update MyTable set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE PK = ? and version = ?
update MyTable set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE PK = ? and version = ? 
update MyTable set col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ? WHERE PK = ? and version = ?
```

Does these updating a row just after insert in a transaction causing deadlock in sql server?

By the way I have test it with mySQL and found no problem.

***Update 1***
I have got a fix accidentally which giving me result 100 over 100. But not satisfied with reason. I just modified the primary key column data type to `nchar` from `char`. No deadlock found. While I changed it again to previous deadlock is found. What could be the reason of deadlock resolution with data type?

Comment: From a SQL Sever point-of-view we'd need to see the queries and transactions generated.  In general, is the database configured for [READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) isolation?  Which is a best-practice for most new applications.

Comment: Database is in Read Committed Isolation. I will provide the sql logs.

Comment: Can you pls explain why READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT is good ??

Comment: Because readers don't block writers, and writers don't block readers.  And since SELECT queries don't use shared locks, whole classes of deadlocks are impossible.

Comment: But it could also cause some business logic failure which could be severe for a system like financial solution.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, pls see my update.

Comment: Does the LockAquisitionException have any more details, perhaps in getErrorCode, getSQL, getSQLException, getSQLState?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, pls check update. I am working in a isolated environment and its difficult to make logs out in internet. I am making same error in my internet environment and will provide logs soon.